# How to be sure to not lose values when select the ID of last X days in SQL

Tags: sql, date, cron, datediff

To give you a context of my problem: I want to receive by email the ID and date of creation of the stuff **created during the 15 last days**.

I want to call a function **each 15 days** in PHP. I do that by creating a CRON task which be **triggered** each of **1st and 16th of the month**.
This is my request SQL request :

```
SELECT ID,
       creation_date
FROM mytable
WHERE creation_date > DATE_SUB (NOW (), INTERVAL 16 DAY)
```

I'm worried about **losing values**.  What is the good method to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *losing values*? Sample data and desired result might help here.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is using product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution :

Add a column `isNotified` in your table like this :

```
| ID | creation_date | isNotified |
|----|---------------|------------|
| 1  | 2020-03-26    | 1          |
| 2  | 2020-04-09    | 0          |
| 3  | 2020-04-10    | 0          |
```

Then, update your request to select only the non already sent items :

```
SELECT ID,creation_date FROM mytable WHERE isNotified=false
// Send your mail
```

If send is OK, update the column to set `isNotified` as `True` like that :

```
UPDATE mytable SET isNotified = true WHERE isNotified = false
```

Set the CRON tab to trigger **1st** and **15th** of month.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you don't lose any data, I'd have a table for which ID have already been notified:

```
NotificationsLog
ID, batchGuid, batchDate
```

(The batch date is informational only, not needed for this process). In my php I would make a new Guid, then run an insert:

```
INSERT INTO Notifications 
SELECT t.ID, @guidFromPhp, NOW()
FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN notificationslog n on n.id = t.id
WHERE n.ID is null
```

This select gets all new data (new as in not in the log table) thanks to the left join looking for null. All new data is logged against the same batch guid.

Then I would pull the rows out and email them based on that same Guid:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Whatever
FROM mytable t
  INNER JOIN notificationslog n on n.id = t.id
WHERE n.batchGuid = @guidFromPhp
```

No dates needed here, and no data goes missing; the process emails all unemailed data every time it is run. If you run it every 15 days it does everything from the last 15 days (apart from the first tine it runs. Preload the log with all current data to avoid that). If you run it every 30 mins you get data from the last 30 mins

You can enhance the log table with a status if there is a risk emailing will fail (or just delete that entry from n - it will be picked up again next run)